# How do I implement Auth0 log in part way through user journey in an R Shiny golemized app?

Tags: r, shiny, auth0

We have several R Shiny apps that we host on posit connect, develop with golem, and which use Auth0 authentication, implemented with the [Auth0 package for R](https://github.com/curso-r/auth0/tree/master).

The way it works, the function auth0::shinyAppAuth0 replaces the shiny::run_app function so that as soon as the app opens, the user is asked to log in. The code below shows the contents of our run_app.R script.

```
run_app <- function(
  onStart = NULL,
  options = list(),
  enableBookmarking = NULL,
  uiPattern = "/",
  port = 8080,
  ...
) {
  options(shiny.port = port)
  with_golem_options(
    app = auth0::shinyAppAuth0(
      ui = app_ui,
      server = app_server,
      onStart = purrr::partial(eval, expr = global, envir = globalenv()),
      options = options,
      enableBookmarking = enableBookmarking,
      uiPattern = uiPattern
    ),
    golem_opts = list(...)
  )
}
```

We want to create a new app which allows the user to access most of the functionality, with a button to log in, so that after you log in you have full functionality.

We have no idea how to implement this, and wondering if anybody has done this before or if it's even possible.

Any help is appreciated.

So far I cannot think of a way to tackle this problem.

Comment: I would think, depending on the complexity of the app, perhaps just the ability to export a string representing the current state of the app would do it - logging in could be implemented by effectively restarting the app in login-mode with the status string as an additional argument?

Comment: Curious: if you're already using Posit Connect (which does not have a free tier), since it already supports OpenID/OAuth (and Auth0 specifically, see https://docs.posit.co/connect/admin/authentication/oauth2-openid-based/openid-connect/), it would seem that you could just add Auth0 authentication to Connect itself. Are you doing it this way because: (1) you need _some_ apps to be behind Auth0 but not all; or (2) this is in addition to another auth mechanism in Connect (seems an _Inception_ of auth schemes)?

Comment: I haven't read all of `curso-r/auth0`'s documentation, but it seems that your use-case is outside of their initial intent. Have you reached out to the authors to see how to do this? (Is [#91](https://github.com/curso-r/auth0/issues/91) you?) To be clear, oauth is a difficult protocol to get right from use and implementation, and there can easily be unforeseen consequences to things like the above. This is an interesting question, I'll be checking back for updates.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, that's really helpful. [#91](https://github.com/curso-r/auth0/issues/91) is indeed me. Our posit connect system is integrated with my organisation's Azure Active Directory so that internals can access apps freely with their existing accounts. We also host apps on there that are intended for audiences outside the organisation, which is why we use Auth0 additionally. So a variety of Auth schemes rather than an inception. 

Are you suggesting that if we had Auth0 integrated with posit we could have users log in part way through? :)

Comment: I have experience configuring Connect with _one_ auth provider, not sure if/how to configure multiple systems. That would be the ideal mechanism, if possible. I suggest you reach out to your Posit reps to see if that's possible. Outside of that, for your current efforts, with our instance, we are unable to "not require auth" for any of that apps. Our instance requires the user to be authenticated to the auth domain before seeing any part of any app; I don't explicitly configure this (I'm the admin), I think it's a requirement of Connect, not certain though.